# mPDF выдаёт ошибки на php5.1

Tags: php, mpdf

Я скачал mPDF с помощью composer на openserver.
Все замечательно работает под php7.2
Но мне нужно чтоб работало под php5.1

В 5.1 на строке `$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();`

Выдаёт:

> ```
> Warning: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in C:\openserver\OSPanel\domains\pdf\htmlpdf.php on line 13
> Warning: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in C:\openserver\OSPanel\domains\pdf\htmlpdf.php on line 13
> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in C:\openserver\OSPanel\domains\pdf\htmlpdf.php on line 13
> ```

Можно ли это поправить? или как быть вообще?

Comment: _"mPDF 7 requires PHP ^5.6 || ~7.0.0 || ~7.1.0 || ~7.2.0. PHP mbstring and gd extensions have to be loaded."_ даже не знаю, что здесь еще добавить

Comment: NameSpaces работает с версии php 5.3.